# How to enable WebDAV related methods in Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

How to enable WebDAV related methods in Tomcat: LOCK, UNLOCK, PROPFIND etc.? I've installed a servlet that handles these methods but when I try to connect to it the server returns 501 Not Implemented error.

Standard GET, POST etc. methods work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by changing web.xml content:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DemoWebDAVServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/dav</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

had to be changed to

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DemoWebDAVServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/dav/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```